# can,t knit in R getting error Error in read_xlsx("Feb'22-divvy-tripdata.xlsx") : could not find function "read_xlsx"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

trying to knit a document in R but keep getting message

> "Error in read_xlsx("Feb'22-divvy-tripdata.xlsx") :    could not find function "read_xlsx"

trying to knit a docutment and expecting a markdown report

Comment: From the error message you probably forgot to add `library(readxl)` to your Rmd. You could also try/use `readxl::read_xlsx("Feb'22-divvy-tripdata.xlsx")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try rather with the function `read_excel()` from the `library(readxl)`.

Or the function `read.xlsx()` of the `library(openxlsx)`. (version 4.2.5.1)

Do not forget to install the packages if there are not already downloaded.